# Convert 1D array sorted by ASCII order to a nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jstree

Assume this below array of objects that sorted by `code` property in ascii order:

```
var codes = [
    { code: '01' },
    { code: '0101' },
    { code: '0102' },
    { code: '010201' },
    { code: '0103' },
    { code: '02' },
    { code: '0201' },
    { code: '0202' },
];
```

How can I convert this to a nested array like this :

```
var nestedCodes = [
    {
        code: '01',
        children: [
            { code: '0101' },
            {
                code: '0102',
                children: [
                    { code: '010201' }
                ]
            },
            { code: '0103' }
        ]
    },
    {
        code: '02',
        children: [
            { code: '0201' },
            { code: '0202' }
        ]
    }
];
```

The structure of codes is like concatenating multiple `0N` that `N` can be a number between 1 and 9. Note that codes come from server and there would be some additional properties beside `code` like `title` but it doesn't matter in this problem.

The main idea here is to make an appropriate format for [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/).

Comment: Sounds like an algorithms class homework/LeetCode question. It'd make a good coding interview question if it isn't one.

Comment: @YangshunTay It's not just a homework question! I'm developing a financial web application and these codes are related to accounting.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Have come up with an answer! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive solution. The idea is to maintain the `path` (obtained as an array via [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex) and the `parent` under which you want to insert the `code` for each recursive call.

The `parent` keeps track of the node you want to pick in the "current" recursive call, and `path` helps in building the `parent` as you keep going deeper:

```js
function insert(d, path, parent, arr) {
  if (path.length === 0) {
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, d));
    return;
  }
  var target = arr.find(e => e.code === parent);
  target.children = target.children || [];
  insert(d, path.slice(1), parent + path[0], target.children);
}

var codes = [
    { code: '01' },
    { code: '0101' },
    { code: '0102' },
    { code: '010201' },
    { code: '0103' },
    { code: '02' },
    { code: '0201' },
    { code: '0202' },
];

var res = codes.reduce((a, c) => {
  var p = c.code.match(/(0[1-9])/g);
  insert(c, p.slice(1), p[0], a);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

The assumption, of course, is that when a `code` is being inserted, its parent has already been inserted before.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled quite a bit to write the recursive function that will build the required structure. Found the answer [here](http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/)

But to do that, you must first add `parent` property to each of your `codes` array. 
I did that on the assumption that each `code` has a parent that is equivalent to the code itself except for the last two bytes.

```js
var codes = [{code: '01'    },
             {code: '0101'  },
             {code: '0102'  },
             {code: '010201'},
             {code: '0103'  },
             {code: '02'    },
             {code: '0201'  },
             {code: '0202'  },
          ];

// add parents to each code
codes.forEach(function(c) {
  if (c.code.length > 2) {
    c.parent = c.code.substr(0, c.code.length - 2);
  } else {
    c.parent = 'root';
  }
});



function find_children(arr, parent) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i in arr) {
    
    if (arr[i].parent == parent) {
      
      var children = find_children(arr, arr[i].code);

      if (children.length) {
        arr[i].children = children;
      }
      out.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return out;
}

var nested = find_children(codes,'root');
console.log(nested);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is a little long but pretty easy to understand in my opinion. It's extremely robust - does not require the array to be sorted and doesn't require `01` to exist to process `0102` (in case it's needed). The code can be much shorter without handling these cases, but I thought you might be need this.

Firstly, create a object-based tree data structure out of the data. This tree has keys and values, and is very efficient to build because accessing by index is O(1). Next, convert the object-based tree into the final array-based tree data structure by traversing the object-based tree and then converting each layer into arrays.

I also make heavy use of recursion since recursion is well suited for creating and traversing trees.

Compared to the other answers, my algorithm has better time complexity because I create a dictionary/object which has O(1) access when creating the tree. The other algorithms do a search within each layer, which is inefficient. My algorithm runs in O(N) whereas the other answers here are shorter but run in O(N^2).

Just copy the `format` function into your code and it should be good to use.

```js
const codes = [
    { code: '01' },
    { code: '0101' },
    { code: '0102' },
    { code: '010201' },
    { code: '0103' },
    { code: '02' },
    { code: '0201' },
    { code: '0202' },
];

function format(codes) {
  // Splits the string into an array of 2-character strings.
  const SPLIT_REGEX = /.{2}(?=(.{2})+(?!.))|.{2}$/g;
  const codeFragments = codes.map(obj => obj.code.match(SPLIT_REGEX));

  // 1. Represent the data as a tree which is more efficient to build.
  const tree = {};
  function createTree(tree, fragments) {
    let node = tree;
    fragments.forEach(fragment => {
      if (!node[fragment]) {
        node[fragment] = {};
      }
      node = node[fragment];
    });
  }
  codeFragments.forEach(fragments => createTree(tree, fragments));
  /* tree will have the structure:
  {
    "01": {
      "01": {},
      "02": {
        "01": {}
      },
      "03": {}
    },
    "02": {
      "01": {},
      "02": {}
    }
  }
  */

  // 2. Convert the tree structure into the desired format.
  function generateCodesFromTree(tree, previous) {
    const nestedCodes = [];
    Object.keys(tree).forEach(treeNode => {
      const code = previous + treeNode;
      const children = generateCodesFromTree(tree[treeNode], code);
      const nestedCode = { code };
      if (children.length > 0) {
        nestedCode.children = children;
      }
      nestedCodes.push(nestedCode);
    });
    return nestedCodes;
  }

  return generateCodesFromTree(tree, '');
}

console.log(format(codes));
```

Comment: I tested all the answers(except joven28's answer because of its imprecise result) and slider's answer was the fastest : https://jsperf.com/conv-1d-arr-sorted-by-ascii-order-to-nested-arr

Comment: @AmirhosseinDZ What assumptions can we make about your code beside it being sorted? Can we assume with if there's `010201`, there will be a `0102` present? If we can assume that, a lot more optimization can be done.

Your benchmark is not accurate. You wouldn't see the full picture by testing on your small set of codes. Here's a better benchmark with 1000 rows: https://jsperf.com/conv-1d-arr-sorted-by-ascii-order-to-nested-arr/5. 

If you look at the results of this benchmark, slider's answer errored out, Ahmad's answer is fastest but the answer is wrong because of above assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be achieved by using a recursive approach. Try this one.

```js
let codes = [
    { code: '01' },
    { code: '0101' },
    { code: '0102' },
    { code: '010201' },
    { code: '0103' },
    { code: '02' },
    { code: '0201' },
    { code: '0202' },
];

roots = codes.filter(c => c.code.length === 2);

roots.forEach(c => assign(c));

console.log(roots);

function assign(code) {
  codes.forEach(c => {
    if (c !== code) {
      if (code.code === c.code.slice(0, code.code.length)) {
        code.children = !code.children ? [c] : [...code.children, c];
        assign(code.children[code.children.length - 1]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```